# Filtering DataFrame by condition on date index

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas series  with values by using `frame['date_created'].value_counts().sort_index()`

```
2013-10     1
2014-12     1
2015-02     1
2015-03     1
2015-09     1
2016-02     6
2016-03     1
2017-05     5
2017-07     2
2017-08    13
2017-09    40
2017-10    47
2017-11    40
2017-12    26
2018-01    16
```

but I want to filter this series to get data with dates of 2017 and above. how can I filter this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `str[...]` slicing

Straightforward, if you're dealing with a string index, then slice, cast, and compare:

```
v = frame['date_created'].value_counts().sort_index()
v_2017 = v[v.index.str[:4].astype(int) >= 2017]
```

```
print(v_2017)

2017-05     5
2017-07     2
2017-08    13
2017-09    40
2017-10    47
2017-11    40
2017-12    26
2018-01    16
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

---

#### `pd.to_datetime`

Alternatively, cast to datetime—

```
v_2017 = v[pd.to_datetime(v.index).year >= 2017]
print(v_2017)

2017-05     5
2017-07     2
2017-08    13
2017-09    40
2017-10    47
2017-11    40
2017-12    26
2018-01    16
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_created': ['2013-10','2014-12',
                                    '2015-02','2015-03',
                                    '2015-09','2016-02',
                                    '2016-03','2017-05',
                                    '2017-07','2017-08',
                                    '2017-09','2017-10',
                                    '2017-11','2017-12',
                                    '2018-01'],
                    'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 5, 2, 13, 40, 47, 40, 26, 16]})

print(df[df['date_created'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0])).gt(2016)])
#    count date_created
#7       5      2017-05
#8       2      2017-07
#9      13      2017-08
#10     40      2017-09
#11     47      2017-10
#12     40      2017-11
#13     26      2017-12
#14     16      2018-01
```